# How to generate parameter URL automatically in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’ve been request array from API and it only appears 20 array per page. Meanwhile, total results are thousands array.

This is the service.ts I’ve made.

```
   getNow() {

        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
       headers.append('Accept', 'application/vnd.api+json');

       params.set("api_key","4285b6347f0429f60f6364ca644beab2");
        params.set("page", "1")

       let options = new RequestOptions({
         headers: headers,
         search: params
        });

        return this.http.get(this.API+"movie/now_playing", options)
         .map(
         (res: Response) => {
            return res.json()
        })   }
```

In home.ts I made

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';  import { NavController }
 from 'ionic-angular';  import { ServiceProvider } from '../../providers/service/service';

 @Component({   
     selector: 'page-home',   
     templateUrl: 'home.html' })

 export class HomePage {

   public Now: any;

   constructor(
     public navCtrl: NavController,
     public service: ServiceProvider ) {

   }
      ionViewDidLoad() {   
 this.service.getNow().subscribe(

      HomePage =>{
        this.Now = HomePage.results;
        console.log(this.Now)
      }, (e)=>{
        console.log(e)
      }    )   }

 }
```

I need to change the number at `params.set("page", "1" )` in service.ts automatically, when I use the button to load more array from the next page in home.html. So how do I make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering you know the logic for auto-incrementing the page number. 
so to pass a parameter in URL you need to accept a parameter in your service like

```
    getNow(page:string,
pageNumber:number) {

            let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json');
           headers.append('Accept', 'application/vnd.api+json');

           params.set("api_key","4285b6347f0429f60f6364ca644beab2");
            params.set(page, pageNumber)

           let options = new RequestOptions({
             headers: headers,
             search: params
            });

            return this.http.get(this.API+"movie/now_playing", options)
             .map(
             (res: Response) => {
                return res.json()
            })   }
```

and in your TS file, you should pass the auto-incremented value or your logic value like

```
ionViewDidLoad() {   
 this.service.getNow(page,pageNumber).subscribe(

      HomePage =>{
        this.Now = HomePage.results;
        console.log(this.Now)
      }, (e)=>{
        console.log(e)
      }    )   }
```

the variable page and pageNumber should be declared in the component, and pass every time while calling your service function.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kale, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Your most welcome brother, if you found this helpful you can mark this as an answer. Which will help others to let it know .happy coding